# qt QVector push_back can not useful

Tags: qt, qvector

I have a very strange question. In my project, `QVector` can not use `push_back()` to add value, but vector can use it; like this:

```
void Widget::SplitStr(string s, QVector<string> &v, const string c)
{
    string::size_type pos1, pos2;

    pos2 = s.find(c);
    pos1 = 0;

    while(string::npos != pos2)
    {
        v.push_back(s.substr(pos1, (pos2-pos1+c.size()-1)));
        pos1 = pos2 + c.size();
        pos2 = s.find(c, pos1);
    }
    if(pos1 != s.length())
        v.push_back(s.substr(pos1));
}
```

[image: come form vs IDE]

This is a Qt project. It is only in this project that I have the strange problem. If anyone can help me, I will appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: my qt is 5.3,add QCustomPlot to project

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have undefined behavior elsewhere in your project, and it corrupts the state. But you also have no error checking: **the function doesn't terminate when `c.empty() == true`** - it will keep adding copies of the input string until it runs out of memory. Perhaps that is what happens.

Comment: I appreciate your reply to my question。In fact,It's not just this function that has this result，That's the whole project。And if change QVector to vector, there is no problem。Thanks again！

Comment: @莫Edison_M79 Then it's very clear that you have undefined behavior elsewhere in the project. **If you're iterating on a `QVector`, make sure you don't attempt to modify it while you do - `std::vector` usually hides this problem for you, but it's no less wrong no matter which of the two vectors you're using.**